# Найти значение с помощью регулярки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно найти значение в следующей строке.

```
\n        'host'=>    'значение',
```

Необходимо учитывать, что могут использоваться одинарные и двойные кавычки, а так же любое количество пробельных символов. Долго ломаю голову, но не получается.

Comment: А внутри значения могут  быть другие кавычки (не такие в которые оно заключено) или может могут быть даже такие же, то экранированные  обратной косой чертой или еще как ?

Comment: Могут, но бог бы с ним. Это обычный хеш PHP, где нужно найти значение ключа host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После стрелки, ноль или более пробелов, одинарная или двойная кавычка, любой символ до  одинарной или двойной кавычки:

`host['"]\s*\=>\s*['"](.*?)['"]`

После комментариев.
Если хотите подключить фал и получить из него результат:

```
$array = require('path/to/.settings.php');
$array['connections']['value']['default']['host'];
$array['connections']['value']['default']['login'];
$array['connections']['value']['default']['password'];
```

Если внутри битрикса, примерно так:

```
use Bitrix\Main\Config as Conf;

$configuration = Conf\Configuration::getInstance();
$array = $configuration->get('connections');
$array['default']['host'];
$array['default']['login'];
$array['default']['password'];
```

Comment: Спасибо, но необходимо отталкиваться, что это хеш и в хеше необходимо найти значения ключа host

Comment: может вы все данные, в целом виде, отобразите, может вам и регулярки не нужны

Comment: к сожалению, думаю, что без них не обойдется. Нужной найти параметры подключения к bd ('host'  'database' 'login'  'password' ) Пример файла: https://gist.github.com/SidiGi/f6ceccd9e7bdd1d5e12e

Comment: Ну по ссылке как минимум 3-и файла. И к чему они? Вы саму задачу опишите, что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: В файле .settings.php, необходимо найти значение ключей 'host' 'database' 'login' 'password'

Comment: .settings.php возвращает массив, и что бы получить значения - $array['connections']['value']['default']['host'], $array['connections']['value']['default']['login'], $array['connections']['value']['default']['password']

Comment: Спасибо, но задача ставится именно на регулярные выражения, т.к . значение нужно будет получить в ruby. Да и сама задача подразумевает, что необходимо все сделать в одно регулярное выражение, получить чистое значение, чтобы потом его этим же регекспом и найти для замены.

Comment: @AlexH, разве регулярка из ответа не находит значение host? https://regex101.com/r/ixXeYG/1